# multiple submit button to submit the form in index page in cakephp 3.x

Tags: jquery, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have index.ctp page where i have submit button for each row and i have to submit the form. But while submitting the form always the last row id is going that id should be each row wise.

I have mentioned the code below. Here right now form is submitting but **supplier** is always going one id it's not updating as per row. where i have to do the modification to send **supplier** row wise by submitting the form?

```
   <?= $this->Form->create($prSuppliers, ['id'=>'createform','url' => ['action' => 'sendinquiry']]); ?>        
  <table id="example2" class="products_table table table-bordered table-hover">
   <?php foreach ($prSuppliers as $CompanyKey=>$CompanyVal){ ?>
            <tr class='tableRow'>
           <td>
            <?php
            echo $this->Form->input('supplier',array('type'=>'hidden','value'=> $CompanyVal->company_master_id));
            $options = array
            (
                    'value' => $CompanyVal->company_master_id,
                    'id' => 'submitButton',
                    'div' => false,
                    'class'=>'submitButton btn btn-success'
            );
            echo  $this->Form->button('Create Inquiry',$options);

            ?>              
           </td>
           </tr>

   <?php }?>
  </table>
   <?= $this->Form->end() ?>

  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
   $(".tableRow").each(function(){
        var _this=$(this);

        $(_this).find(".submitButton").click(function(){
            var supplier=$(_this).find(".supplier").val();
            $(_this).find(".supplier").val(supplier);
            $("form").submit();         
            //return false;
        });

    }); 


    }); 
</script>
```

Comment: you are creating an unique form for the whole table. Instead you have to create a single form for each row. Put form->create and form->end inside the foreach loop

Comment: this makes zero sense: `var supplier=$(_this).find(".supplier").val();            $(_this).find(".supplier").val(supplier);` - also navigate from the buttons: `$(function() {
      $(".submitButton").on("click",function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var $row = $(this).closest("tr"), supplier=$row.find(".supplier").val();`

Comment: On every row's button call a javascript function and pass the data to that function, from that function create an ajax call and pass the data to PHP function for further submission.